# React - VPS - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, vps

Spring + React project successfully launched **on VPS** and when the page should be displayed **I get this error in the browser:** 
[image]

I don't know how to find the mistake, everything worked normally locally.

Comment: Have you checked what's in code under this line? Put a breakpoint there and go through call stack to see what's being used here that is undefined or null. Without a code we can't tell anything.

Comment: @tswistak Shows error here: const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(async function* () {}).prototype); I don't know how to put an breakpoint on a VPS

Comment: You are in Chrome's devtools. Just put a breakpoint on the line where it shows code. Alternatively, you can set in devtools to pause on all exceptions and try to find out what's going on. Unfortunately, that code is too little data for us to know what's going on.

Comment: @tswistak Okay then, I'm writing if I find out a mistake. Can I get your email, if you have free time for some questions about deployment?